# Gradle project nesting

Tags: android, gradle

I'm having trouble compiling my project. My current structure looks like this.

```
root
    library
        internal
    application
```

This builds if I add `compile project(':library:internal')`to build.gradle inside library. The problem is that I want library to be a separate project from root and build on it's own. In that case it needs to be `compile project(':internal')`. This would work if I add library as a binary, but I'd like to add it as source for now at least.

Answer (score 0):

> I want library to be a separate project from root and build on it's own

Then you should move the 'library' into the directory where the 'root' is and make it a separate project. Then you can write `includeFlat 'library'` in the 'settings.gradle' of the 'root' and `compile project(':library')` in the 'build.gradle' ('internal' should be included automatically).